# How to pass a function as parameter into another function in C++?

Tags: c++

my compiler gives the following error. Please help me with the syntax.

```
int sum(int a, int b);
int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}

int mult(int c, std::function<int(int a, int b)> sum2);
int mult(int c, std::function<int(int a, int b)> sum2) {
    return sum2 * c;
}

int main() {
    cout << mult(5, sum(2, 2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to do too much. I doubt if you know the basics of function. I would suggest you read the basics first.

Comment: "my compiler gives the following error"... that's code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using it all wrong, you should not *call* the `sum` function in the call to `mult`, instead you call it *in* `mult`:

```
int mult(int c, std::function<int(int a, int b)> sum2) {
    return sum2(2, 2) * c;
}

int main() {
    cout << mult(5, sum);
    return 0;
}
```

What you are doing now is passing the result of the `sum` call in `main`, and that result is an integer and not a function.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the function as a parameter.  You are passing the return value of the function.  Change mult's second parameter to be an int.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually passing the value 4 to the function `mult`. You should do this instead:

```
mult (5, sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many errors :

1. missing `#include <iostream>` and `#include <functional>`
2. `cout` should be `std::cout`
3. multiplying functor with int makes no sense, since such operator* is not defined. Try for example this:

   ```
   int mult(int c, std::function<int(int a, int b)> sum2) {
       return sum2(2,2) * c;
   }
   int main() {
       std::cout << mult(5, sum);
   }
   ```